BTRFS - tree first key mismatch detected
Every other hour, my system's root partition turns to read-only because of this BTRFS error:
BTRFS error (device nvme0n1p3): tree first key mismatch detected, bytenr=11981209600 parent_transid=3110 key expected=(2355470336,168,69632) has=(2355994624,168,69632)

It's always the same "bytenr" - fsck.btrfs did not bring up errors.
How can I repair that error?

"fsck.btrfs did not bring up errors." – See man 8 fsck.btrfs: "fsck.btrfs - do nothing, succesfully". :D Read the whole man page. Later it says "If you wish to check the consistency of a BTRFS filesystem or repair a damaged filesystem, see btrfs-check(8). By default filesystem consistency is checked, the repair mode is enabled via the --repair option (use with care!)". I do not know if btrfs-check can help in your case, I do not know if it's your best option (therefore not an answer); but at least now you know why fsck.btrfs "did not bring up errors".

Thanks, but btrfs-check also reports no errors. I am curious, this btrfs stuff is not marked experimental, also it's recommended by fedora - but it seems to be kind of buggy, unstable and not user friendly. I'll set up everything from scratch with ext4 - as did the other 15 years...
